# Adjusting Background Color of Column using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, web-applications

[image]

This is my webapp, currently it looks for what day of the week the current day falls on and highlights that day on the table. It also does it for the day two weeks from the current day.

However i'm having trouble with the next part, I need to adjust the highlight if the current day or the day two weeks away falls on a holiday. Right now the holiday highlight(Purple) is overriding the yellow highlight, but I need the yellow highlight to show up for 7/5 since 7/4 is a holiday.

The business rule that makes up these highlighting rules are as follows: the current day will be highlighted and the day 2 weeks out will be highlighted. Basically, the first day and the last day of this 10 day period will be highlighted yellow. But if the first or the last day falls on a holiday then the highlight needs to be moved to the next day.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to accomplish this? I don't need the full answer, but a nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

### Index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="app.css" />
      <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="js/domo.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>      
  </head>
  <body ng-app="rcr_sched" ng-controller="main">
      <div id="mydiv">
        <table>
            <tr id="printc"><button id="print" class="fa fa-print fa-3x" onclick="print('#mydiv')"></button>
            <button id="print2" onclick="print('#mydiv')">Print Page</button>
            <button id="today">Today/SLDD</button>
            <button id="PTO">PTO</button>
            <button id="Hol">Hol</button>
            </tr>
            <tr height="40" id="header">
                <th ng-repeat="prop in columns">{{prop.date}}</th>
            </tr>  
            <tr ng-repeat="r in data">
                <td align="center" ng-repeat="prop2 in columns" class="{{getColor(r.TeamRank, r.Team, prop2.title)}}" style="{{isPTO(prop2.title, 'PTO' + prop2.title, r['PTO' + prop2.title]) || isHol(prop2.title, 'Hol' + prop2.title, r['Hol' + prop2.title])}}">
                    {{r[prop2.title]}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
          <hr id="end">
      </div>      
  </body>
</html>
```

### App.js

```
var app = angular.module('rcr_sched',['ngRoute']);

 app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
       .when('/',{
           templateUrl:'index.html',
           controller:'main'
       })
       .when('drill',{
           templateUrl:'drill.html'
       })
//       .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});  
    }
 ]);
//Range Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded

app.controller('main', ['$scope', '$location', function ($scope, $location){
        $scope.goNext = function(view){
            $location.path('/');
        }
        $scope.data = [];
        $scope.columns = [];
        $scope.currentDate = new Date();
        $scope.calculateDate = function() {
            var x = new Date();
            return {
                'MonThisWk': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() - (x.getDay() - 1)), title:'MonThisWk'},
                'TueThisWk': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() - (x.getDay() - 2)),title:'TueThisWk'},
                'WedThisWk': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() - (x.getDay() - 3)),title:'WedThisWk'},
                'ThuThisWk': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() - (x.getDay() - 4)),title:'ThuThisWk'},
                'FriThisWk': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() - (x.getDay() - 5)),title:'FriThisWk'},
                'MonNextWk': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() + 7 - (x.getDay() - 1)),title:'MonNextWk'},
                'TueNextWk': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() + 7 - (x.getDay() - 2)),title:'TueNextWk'},
                'WedNextWk': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() + 7 - (x.getDay() - 3)),title:'WedNextWk'},
                'ThuNextWk': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() + 7 - (x.getDay() - 4)),title:'ThuNextWk'},
                'FriNextWk': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() + 7 - (x.getDay() - 5)),title:'FriNextWk'},
                'Mon2Wks': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() + 14 - (x.getDay() - 1)),title:'Mon2Wks'},
                'Tue2Wks': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() + 14 - (x.getDay() - 2)),title:'Tue2Wks'},
                'Wed2Wks': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() + 14 - (x.getDay() - 3)),title:'Wed2Wks'},
                'Thu2Wks': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() + 14 - (x.getDay() - 4)),title:'Thu2Wks'},
                'Fri2Wks': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() + 14 - (x.getDay() - 5)), title:'Fri2Wks'}
            }
        }
        $scope.isPTO = function(rowTitle, ptoTitle, value) {
            if (rowTitle == (ptoTitle.replace('PTO', '')) && value) {
                return 'background-color: #7DD961;';
            }
            return '';

        }
        $scope.isHol = function(rowTitle, holTitle, value ){
            if (rowTitle == (holTitle.replace('Hol', '')) && value){
                return 'background-color: #c3aed6;';
            }
            return '';
        }
        function print(elem){
            Popup($('<div/>').append($(elem).clone()).html());
        }

        function Popup(data) 
{
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=400,width=600');
    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>my div</title>');
    mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ddincludes/mainstyle.css" type="text/css" />');
    mywindow.document.write('</head><body>');
    mywindow.document.write(data);
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');


    mywindow.print();
  //  mywindow.close();
    return true;
}

        $scope.dateOptions = $scope.calculateDate();
        $scope.getColor = function(teamRank, team, prop) {
            let today = new Date();

            if (prop == 'Team' || prop == 'TeamMember') 
            {
                if (team == 'Unassigned') 
                {
                    return "grayClass";
                }
                else if (team == 'Gold One') 
                {
                    return "goldClass";
                }
                else if (team == 'Red One' || team == 'Red Two') 
                {
                    return "redClass";
                }
                else if (team == 'Blue One' || team == 'Blue Two') {
                    return "blueClass"
                }
                else if (team == 'Green One') 
                {
                    return "greenClass";
                }
                else
                {
                    return "grayClass";
                }
            }
            if(prop == 'MonThisWk' || prop == 'Mon2Wks')
           {
               if(today.getDay() == 1)
               {
                    return "highlightClass";   
               } 
           }
           if(prop == 'TueThisWk' || prop == 'Tue2Wks')
           {
               if(today.getDay() == 2)
               {
                    return "highlightClass";   
               }
           }
           if(prop == 'WedThisWk' || prop == 'Wed2Wks')
           {
               if(today.getDay() == 3)
               {
                    return "highlightClass";   
               }
           }
           if(prop == 'ThuThisWk' || prop == 'Thu2Wks')
           {
               if(today.getDay() == 4)
               {
                    return "highlightClass";   
               }
           }
            if(prop == 'FriThisWk' || prop == 'Fri2Wks')
           {
               if(today.getDay() == 5)
               {
                    return "highlightClass";   
               }
           }

        }

        domo.get('data/v1/master?fields=Team,TeamMember,TotalJobs,NDD,Past,MonThisWk,TueThisWk,WedThisWk,ThuThisWk,FriThisWk,MonNextWk,TueNextWk,WedNextWk,ThuNextWk,FriNextWk,Mon2Wks,Tue2Wks,Wed2Wks,Thu2Wks,Fri2Wks,Future,TotalJobs,PTOMonThisWk,PTOTueThisWk,PTOWedThisWk,PTOThuThisWk,PTOFriThisWk,PTOMon2Wks,PTOTue2Wks,PTOWed2Wks,PTOThu2Wks,PTOFri2Wks,PTOMonNextWk,PTOTueNextWk,PTOWedNextWk,PTOThuNextWk,PTOFriNextWk,HolMonThisWk,HolTueThisWk,HolWedThisWk,HolThuThisWk,HolFriThisWk,HolMonNextWk,HolTueNextWk,HolWedNextWk,HolThuNextWk,HolFriNextWk,HolMon2Wks,HolTue2Wks,HolWed2Wks,HolThu2Wks,HolFri2Wks&groupby=TeamRank,Team,TeamMember&orderby=TeamRank')
            .then(function(data){
                $scope.data = data;
                for (prop in data[0]) {
                    if ($scope.dateOptions[prop]) {
                        var newDate = $scope.dateOptions[prop];
                        var formattedProp = {date: (newDate.date.getMonth() + 1).toString() + '/' + newDate.date.getDate().toString(), title: newDate.title};
                    }
                    else {
                        var formattedProp = {date: prop, title: prop};
                    }
                    $scope.columns.push(formattedProp);
                }
                $scope.$apply();
            })
    }]);
```

### App.css

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: xx-small;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    -moz-print-color-adjust: exact;
}

a{
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 15px
}

table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

th{
    border: 1px solid #191919;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

td{
    border: 1px solid #191919;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

td{
    background-color: white;
}

hr {
    margin: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #191919;
    width: 1409px;
}

.redClass {
    background-color: #ff8d80;
}

.blueClass {
    background-color: #9adcfc;
}

.grayClass {
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
}

.goldClass {
    background-color: #ffdf32;
}

.greenClass {
    background-color: #b0e89f;
}

.ptoClass {
    background-color: #52D08F;
}

.highlightClass {
    background-color: #FEF65B;
}


.hideClass {
    background-color: white;
    color: white;
}


#Today{
    background-color: #FEF65B;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    border: 1px solid #FEF65B;
}

#PTO{
   background-color: #7DD961;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    border: 1px solid #7DD961;
}

#Hol{
    background-color: #c3aed6;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    border: 1px solid #c3aed6;
}
#header{
    background-color: #6fcdfc;
    font-size: 19px;
}

#print{
    background-color: white;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    border: none;
}

#print2{
    border: none;
    background-color: white;
    align-content: right;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;

}
/*
td:nth-child(1){
    border-left-color: #2F4F4F;
}
td:nth-child(2){
    border-right-color: #2F4F4F;
}
td:nth-child(3){
    border-right-color: #2F4F4F;
}
td:nth-child(4){
    border-right-color: #2F4F4F;
}
td:nth-child(9){
    border-right-color: #2F4F4F;
}
td:nth-child(14){
    border-right-color: #2F4F4F;
}
td:nth-child(19){
    border-right-color: #2F4F4F;
}

td:nth-child(20){
    border-right-color: #2F4F4F; 
}
td:nth-child(21){
    border-right-color: black;
}
*/
td:nth-child(n+3){
    font-weight:bold;
}

th:nth-child(n+22){
    display: none;
}

td:nth-child(n+22) {
    display: none;    
}



@media print{
    #print{
        display: none;
    }

    #print2{
        display: none;
    }

    #link{
        display: none;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best way to go about it, but I simply edited my if statements that were controlling the yellow highlighting. Here is what all of those statements look like now:

```
if(prop == 'Tue2Wks')
            {
                if(today.getDay() == 1 && prop.HolMon2Wks !== null)
                {
                 return "highlightClass";
                }
                else if(today.getDay() == 2 && prop.HolTue2Wks !== null)
                {
                    return '';
                }
                else if(today.getDay() == 2)
                {
                    return "highlightClass";
                }
            }
```

Of course each one is slightly different depending on the day.